# Filling in these gaps in door frame

Tags: wood, door-frame, gap

One of my doors has these gaps on the bottom and side panels.  Is there a way I can fix/fill them somehow?

[image]

Adding more photos below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the trim wasn't properly toed into the door frame. However, it's also possible that there is drywall or a 2x that's proud of the doorframe.
You can fix the gap with painters caulk. However, I would pull the trim off and determine what is causing the gap. If it's drywall it should be easy enough to cut out to fit the trim properly. If it's framing causing it you can plane it down. From there the trim shouldn't be an issue.
**Second Edit**
Some really good points being made by contributors on possible structural issues. Some questions:

- Is the trim separation a recent development since you moved in?
- Are there any other signs of potential structural shifting in the house?
- Cracks in the walls, ceiling, basement, foundation?
- Doorways that are obviously out of plumb - including this one?
- Did you have a professional do a home inspection when you bought?

These are all indicators of possible structural shifts that should be assessed by a professional through an on-site inspection and are probably beyond the scope of what we can tell you here.

Comment: Your hinge looks like its been installed wrong or is loosening up+

Comment: @JACK: would you mind elaborating on what makes you say that? And what I need to do to fix it, if you happen to know?

Comment: @David  You need to unscrew it , pull the door out to the hinge knuckles and screw it back in. You might have to trim some of the door to get the hinge in further.

Comment: @JACK: Many thanks. Will do that.

Comment: @HoneyDo: Point of clarification, what is a 2x? You mean 2x4?

Comment: Yes. Could even be a 2x6.

Comment: I do not understand why anybody would recommend using silicone caulk for caulking door trim???? You do realize it cannot be painted and can ruin the look an item, if not used in its proper manner and place!

Comment: @JACK - I've used paintable silicone caulk for any number of interior and exterior jobs. You're right that it typically is used outdoor for its weatherability and I should have cautioned OP to make sure it is paintable - but I assumed he would know that. It can be a little harder to work with but paintable silicone caulk works very well on trim and it's durable. The painters caulk I mentioned also works well.

Comment: @JACK - Edited out silicone caulk for simplicity.

Comment: Paintable silicone yes, but the post had just silicone. I have never had any reason to use paintable silicone, since there are so many easier types of caulk to use out there. And by the way, there are 2 Jacks out here.

Comment: @HoneyDo  That's little Jack...... not big JACK...... lol   I just commented on the hinge.

Comment: @JACK and HoneyDo: I added a few more photos that are slightly larger and show the entire door frame. Based on these, would your recommendation on what I need to do to fix this change?

Comment: For everyone here, assume I know nothing. This is my first house and I'm just making it up as I go. This community and the advice you guys provide is invaluable to me.

Comment: @David How about a picture of the inside of the hinges, with the door open.

Answer (score 4):

Something isn't right if I understand the picture correctly. I see that there used to be caulking that filled the gap and now the gap is wider. This means something is moving. Moving things in a structure is not a good thing. You need to find the source of the issue to be able to address it.

Here is the first thing that I would check. Note that the door opens left. This causes a force to the right on the lower hinge. It's quite possible that the connection of the door frame is inadequate or has failed which is forcing the door frame to move to the right. A lot of times this connection is just a nail. A way to test to see if this is the issue is to open the door and carefully lift up and then push down on the door handle, if there is movement of the bottom of the door frame at the wall, this is probably the issue. Also, the gap will be larger at the bottom of the door than then top.

Report back?

Comment: Thanks! I'll edit the post with slightly better pictures and show you the entire door frame from top to bottom. At the top things are connected well, but it slowly starts to break apart in the middle and is fully gapped in the bottom.

Comment: Yes exactly as I expected, the door has moved at the bottom from the force due to the weight of the open door. The source of the issue is almost always the connection of the door to the wall framing. A good trick to fix this is to replace one of the hinge screws with a long one. First adjust the door back (open it and shim under it can work). Then shim between the door and wall stud so that when you put in the screw the door framed isn't 'sucked' towards the framing member as this will cause other issues